# Comparing two arrays in angular using ngIf

Tags: angular

In my angular app i have two arrays arr1, arr2, where i am using arr1 to render button in my view using ngFor. I want to change the style of button by comparing the items of arr1 and arr2. if there is a match, i want to apply different styling. How can i implement this please guide me.

app.component.ts

```
arr1 = [{test:1}, {test:2}, {test:3}, {test:4}, {test:5}, {test:6}, {test:7}, {test:8}, {test:9}, {test:10}]
arr2 = [{test:5}, {test:9}]
```

appCopmponent.html

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-1" *ngFor="let data of arr1">
        <input type="button" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="data.test" readonly>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The general use-case for ngIf is to conditionally render elements in the dom and isn't really suitable for changing styling. `ngClass` and/or `ngStyle` are most likely to be suitable for your requirement. https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/how-to-add-a-class-based-on-condition-in-angular/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `[ngClass]` for assigning style class based on your need

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-l1c9t5?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-1" *ngFor="let data of arr1">
        <input [ngClass]="founded(data) ? 'exist' : 'not-exist'" type="button" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="data.test" readonly>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <style>
    input{
      padding: 0 2rem;
      margin: 1rem 0
    }
    .exist{
      border: orange solid 5px;
    }
    .not-exist{
      border: green solid 5px;
    }
  </style>
```

and code:

```
arr1 = [{test:1}, {test:2}, {test:3}, {test:4}, {test:5}, {test:6}, {test:7}, {test:8}, {test:9}, {test:10}]

arr2 = [{test:5}, {test:9}]


founded(item: {test: number}){
  return !!this.arr2.find(x=>x.test === item.test)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can with using `ngClass` attribute.

*.ts file*

```
arr1 = [{test:1}, {test:2}, {test:3}, {test:4}, {test:5}, {test:6}, {test:7}, {test:8}, {test:9}, {test:10}]
arr2 = [{test:2}, {test:1}];

contains: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.contains = !this.arr2.filter(item => !this.arr1.find(x => x.test === item.test)).length;
  }
```

*on template*

```
<p [ngClass]="contains? 'bg-blue': 'bg-red'">
  Change background based on array comparison
</p>
```

*css file*

```
  .bg-red {
    background-color: red
  }
  .bg-blue {
    background-color: blue
  }
```

Also I created a [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j5ze3c) for you.

Answer (score 1):

Compare your array into the component file.

```
  compareValue(data){
     if(this.arr2.find(o => o.test === data.test)){
       return true;
     }else{
       return false;
   }
}
```

Call the function from html and add your style class using `ngClass`.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-md-1" *ngFor="let data of arr1">
    <input type="button" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'success':compareValue(data)}" [(ngModel)]="data.test" readonly>
  </div>
</div>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yupxet)